# Spring boot integration test with H2 and JPA fails

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, h2, spring-boot-test

I am running a Spring Boot integration test that saves to an in memory H2 database using JPA. There are 2 main entities MyRequest and MyResponse with a one to one relation - a field of type MyResponse is in MyRequest and the test  calls save() on the repository by passing it a MyRequest object. Why does the test fail with this exception? - org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class MyResponse

On inspecting breakpoint, ids of both the MyRequest object and MyResponse inside it are null.

The same error happens using GenerationType.AUTO instead of GenerationType.IDENTITY. Calls to count() and findAll() calls on the repository return 0 and an empty list respectively.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "MySchema", name = "MyRequest")
@Data
public class MyRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "MyRequestID")
    private Integer myRequestId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "myRequestHeader", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private MyResponse myResponse;

    .... Other fields

}


@Entity
@Table(schema = "MySchema", name = "MyResponse")
@Data
public class MyResponse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "MyResponseID")
    private Integer myResponseId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private MyRequest myRequest;

    .... Other fields

}

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyRequest, Integer> {

}

@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.ANY)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    private MyRepository myRepository

    //construct myRequest

    long count = myRepository.count(); //returns 0

    List<MyRequest> all = myRepository.findAll(); //returns empty list

    myRepository.save(myRequest); // fails with exception
}
```

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Comment: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException with its cause as org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class MyResponse

Comment: How are you building your request/response objects and mocking your API? I copied your entities, repository and test and all worked fine.